# url to display image and connecting css in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm new to web development (especially php in CI framework). This question should be a very simple question for you, but i have been googling for a hour and still cant find any solution.

I want to display an image (logo.png in **img** folder) and link a css file (style.css in **style** folder) that i put in **root** directory :

[image]

But when i tried to display the image and link the css, all i got is a **blank** empty **webpage**.
This is my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My First Design</title>
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><img src="../../img/logo.jpg" />My First Web Design</h1>
        <p>
        I have been working on honing, and in some cases, learning new graphical skills in the past few weeks. So, I have been                          extensively watching Adobe Illustrated tutorials and working on my existing Photoshop knowledge and basically trying to                     get a hang of the software beyond basic image editing and digital painting.
        </p>
        <p>
        From a beginner’s point of view, the world of graphical design is quite vast… at times intimidating and there is no limit                           to creative options. One could branch out into any form of graphical design… illustrations or web-design or logo &                                  advertising and so much more. At the same time, one does not need to limit the options to just these.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my `config.php` base_url : `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ciGlassProject/';`

I have tried some different ways like :

1. Use site_url instead of base_url
2. type the url manually
3. Change the `$config['base_url']` value in many ways.
   But, none of them is working.

Comment: can `http://localhost/ciGlassProject/img/logo.jpg` work?

Comment: @pktangyue yes, sorry i think i just miss type the url :D

Comment: THE ANSWER IS : The base(); url is not working coz i forgot to import the helper ($this->load->helper('url')) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the base URL it should work.

```
<img src="http://localhost/ciGlassProject/img/logo.jpg" />
```

A better way to do it is to get your base url using php. That will mean if you mov your site you wont have to change the URL a bunch of times to get it running in a new locateion. For that you can use a simple php call:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/logo.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks :D
The manual url is working now (i think i miss type the '://' part) but, the base_url(); method is not working. The css is also not working coz i use base_url(). The strange thing is, when i look up my older projects, everything that related to base_url() method is just fine.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to import the helper in my controller. Thanks for your help :D